# Pandas - Insert values at specific index and specific column but if there are multiple same index values

Tags: pandas

I am wondering if there's a way to insert some scalar number into a dataframe at specific index and specific column but if there are multiple same index values:

[image: For e]

I have this dataframe with the index value (TEVA US EQUITY) but it appears multiple times (6) in the index. I want to insert a value in the first non-empty row at specific column, so that it looks like

[image]

and the next time I insert values, I want to upload them to the second row (because the second row is the first non-empty row).

[image]

Comment: Does this empty shell of a DataFrame serve any purpose? It seems to only add difficulty in this example. `append` or `concat` will just add a new row at the bottom, no need to have an empty placeholder beforehand

Comment: @ALollz I can start with an empty dataframe and add a row using `append` one at a time but wouldn't it slow down the process if I have hundreds of rows to be added?